# manipulate list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have three lists to make my condition, that is if b is equal to 1 then I want to find the first element in which c was below than a, so then I can get those two indexes subtract them and that is the time.

```
    a = [1.373, 1.374, 1.374, 1.385, 1.385, 1.385, 1.374, 1.374]
    b = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    c = [0, 1.384, 1.385, 1.377, 0, 0, 0, 0]

   view = [(nx, x, nz, z, nl, l) for nx, x in enumerate(a)
           for nl, l in enumerate(b) for nz, z in enumerate(c)
           if (l == 1) & (nz <= nx) & (z > 0) & (z <= x) & (nz == nl)]
```

I created a simple view list that shows all the parameters for better understanding. 
However when I do this I get all the numbers when c is lower and I just want the first elements... I expected to see just `[(3, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (3, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1)]` and I got that:

```
[(3, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (3, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1), (4, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (4, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1), (5, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (5, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1)]

time = [(nx - nz) for nx, x in enumerate(a)
        for nl, l in enumerate(b) for nz, z in enumerate(c)
        if (l == 1) & (nz <= nx) & (z > 0) & (z <= x) & (nz == nl)]
```

How can I get just the first elements when my condition is true?

Comment: please provide a better explanation

Comment: I just want to get the first elements when c is lower or equal than a. 
For example, the result that I got: 
(3, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (3, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1), (4, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (4, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1)
the first two elements are the elements when my condition is true for the first time, because (3, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (3, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1) have unique indices, however (4, 1.385, 1, 1.384, 1, 1), (4, 1.385, 2, 1.385, 2, 1) have the same index as the previous result so they are not the first time when my condition is true instead they are the continuation...

Comment: Why are you using nesting loops? can'y you just use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)? also according to your example there are no `True` values, when `b` is 1 `c[i]` is bigger then `x[i]`

Comment: `b` can't be equal to `1`, because it's `list`!

Comment: You can use the following `view = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)  if y == 1 and 0 < z <= x]` but as i said before there are no results at you case, since at `c[1] > x[1]` and `c[2] > x[2]`

Comment: That is why I cannot use zip, because when they have the same index my condition is never true, if I fix one index and make the other index run until it finds my condition, for the first time not always, I have to write that.

Comment: Is this a good explanation for you case: if `b[i] == 1` iterate over `a` and return the first element where `a[j] >= c[i]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solve without list comprehension and at better time complexity:

```
a = [1.373, 1.374, 1.374, 1.385, 1.385, 1.385, 1.374, 1.374]
b = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
c = [0, 1.384, 1.385, 1.377, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for y_i, y in enumerate(b):
    if y == 1:
        for x_i, x in enumerate(a):
            if x >= c[y_i]:
                # all prints are zero based indexes
                print "iteration {}, x: {}, x index: {} c: {}, c index {}".format(y_i, x, x_i, c[y_i], y_i)
                break
```

Output:

```
iteration 1, x: 1.385, x index: 3 c: 1.384, c index 1
iteration 2, x: 1.385, x index: 3 c: 1.385, c index 2
```

Sometimes it;s easier to start with normal loops when you get the algorithm then you can make it a better code, Also there is no need for 3 for statements.